# Why does margin override marginLeft in Android (same with radius, etc)?

Tags: android, coding-style, margin, android-layout

This makes no sense to me, coming from CSS. In CSS, if you specify a margin and then margin-left, the left margin will assume the more granular value.

In Android, it is the opposite. Same goes for android:radius, and I'm sure other values.

My question is: why?.. It makes no sense. Is there a single reason for doing it this way?

Edit: prompted by trying to find a solution to yet another Google ADT/Android bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7588

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to get an answer to this unless the google dev who implemented this posts here. What are you expecting?

Comment: Well, Google does officially provide support for Android at SO, so why not? :P

Comment: *In CSS, if you specify a margin and then margin-left, the left margin will assume the more granular value.* - this has nothing to do with granularity, the CSS rule found later in the stylesheet overwrites the other one (assuming they have the same specificity).

Comment: Tgr, yeah, OK, you're right. In Android, however, order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same frustration, but if you think about it, which value should be used?  I know in your post you say that CSS uses the "more granular value" but it all boils down to pixels in the end and the result is simply two pixel values that need to be chosen between.  The CSS standard chose to do it one way, Android chose the other, I don't think either approach is wrong, they are just different.

Comment: I disagree - with CSS, you can set the master value and override it only for 1 element. In Android, the master value wipes all of them, so it's not nearly as powerful, thus making you set all 4 values if you want to only override 1.

Comment: yeah, i agree...it's not that one is "chosen" in CSS, it's whichever one is declared last. So you declare padding: 10px, padding-left: 20px; and the padding-left will override padding because it's second.

Comment: So, the lesson here for me is to always use layout_marginLeft / Right / Top / Bottom when defining a style. This gives clients the ability to override when necessary.e